# Can't Populate Database by excel file in Django ( Management Command )

Tags: python, django, pandas, postgresql

Management Command (populatedb.py)

```
import pandas as pd
```

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.apps import apps

class Command(BaseCommand):
help = "Creating model objects according the file path specified"

```
def add_arguments(self, parser):
    parser.add_argument('--path', type=str, help="file path")
    parser.add_argument('--model_name', type=str, help="model name")
    parser.add_argument('--app_name', type=str, help="django app name that the model is connected to")

def handle(self, *args, **options):
    file_path = options['path']
    _model = apps.get_model(options['app_name'], options['model_name'])
    df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
    header = list(df.columns)        

    for row in df:
        _object_dict = {key: value for key, value in zip(header, row)}
        _model.objects.create(**_object_dict)
```

Terminal Error:

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "'a'": "State.country" must be a "Country" instance.
```

Models.py

```
class State(TimeStampModel):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
country = models.ForeignKey(Country,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to=path_and_rename)

def __str__(self) -> str:
    return f"{self.name}"

class Meta:
    db_table = 'states'
    unique_together = ('name', 'country',)
```

Comment: Can you share your model definition? Are you using `django-countries`?

Comment: I've edited my post please see to it @MarkR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the instance of country using state model. You can do something like this.

```
from django.apps import apps
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
import pandas as pd
import csv

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "Creating model objects according the file path specified"

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('--path', type=str, help="file path", default=None)
        parser.add_argument('--model_name', type=str,
                            help="model name", default=None)
        parser.add_argument(
            '--app_name', type=str, help="django app name that the model is connected to", default=None)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        # print(options)
        file_path = options['path']
        if not file_path.endswith('.csv'):
            self.stdout.write('File "%s" is not csv type.' % file_path)
        _model = apps.get_model(options['app_name'], options['model_name'])

        with open(file_path, 'r') as csv_file:
            reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
            header = next(reader)
            for row in reader:
                _object_dict = {key: value for key, value in zip(header, row)}

                opts = _model._meta
                print(_object_dict)
                fields = [field for field in opts.get_fields() if not field.many_to_many and not field.one_to_many]
                # print('fields', fields)
                # other_fields = [field for field in opts.get_fields() if field.many_to_many or field.one_to_many ]
                other_fields = [field for field in opts.get_fields() if field.many_to_many or field.one_to_many or field.many_to_one]
                # print('other fields', other_fields)
                id = _object_dict.get('id')
                try:
                    obj = _model.objects.get(pk=id)
                    print('fetched obj', obj)
                    print('object already exists in database')
                    continue
                except _model.DoesNotExist:
                    try:
                        if other_fields:
                            for field in other_fields:
                                rel_model = opts.get_field(
                                    field.verbose_name).related_model #country model from state
                                try:
                                    rel_obj = rel_model.objects.get(
                                        id=_object_dict.get(field.verbose_name))
                                except rel_model.DoesNotExist:
                                    rel_obj = rel_model.objects.create(id=_object_dict.get(field.verbose_name))

                                _object_dict.update({field.verbose_name: rel_obj})
                                print(_object_dict)
                    except _model.DoesNotExist:
                        pass
                    obj = _model.objects.create(**_object_dict)
                    print('creating obj')
                except _model.MultipleObjectsReturned:
                    print('multiple entries returned for this id', id)
                    pass
```